# How To Dispose Old Sprite Objects With All Event Listener References?

Tags: actionscript-3, garbage-collection, dispose, event-listener

In ActionScript-3 in my level editor I have for each level a new object. Old level objects are removed from stage. So only 1 level object is at stage. I don't keep them in an array or something hoping that garbage collection disposes them for me. My problem seems to be that methods of old objects are still referenced by event listeners that would fire events to the new object and also to the old ones. Old objects are not on stage and therefore invisible but when saving I notice that the old levels have a state caused by editing a newer level.

Now: How can I dispose my objects **for sure** ?

edit: I also have some event listeners added to stage (KeyDown, MouseMove). Might those few be the problem and others that are just added to the object are removed with the object automatically ?

Comment: If you add an event listener to _anything_ that is an ongoing concern (like, oh, the state), then of course the object that contains that function is still referenced (how else could the function get called when the event fires?). Look at the removeEventListener function. Also, avoid setTimeOut, as it can also cause memory leaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to simply setup your event listeners to use weak references by setting the `userWeakReference` of [`addEventListener()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29) property to true:

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler, false, 0, true);
```

A better pattern is to setup a lifecycle of listeners, such as add listeners on [`Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#ADDED_TO_STAGE), then remove them on [`Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#REMOVED_FROM_STAGE)

In your constructor, listen for `Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE`:

```
// listen for added to stage
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
```

When your class is added to stage, apply your listeners and listen for `Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE`:

```
protected function addedToStageHandler(event):void
{
    // remove added to sage handler, listen for removed from stage
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
    addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedFromStageHandler);

    // setup listeners for class
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
    addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOutHandler);
    addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
}
```

When your class is removed from stage, remove remaining listeners:

```
protected function removedFromStageHandler(event):void
{
    // remove removed from sage handler
    removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedFromStageHandler);

    // remove listeners for class
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler);
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOutHandler);
    removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
}
```

Even better yet is to implement a `dispose()` function for your class:

```
public function dispose():void
{
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClickHandler);
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mouseMoveHandler);
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOutHandler);
    removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
}
```

Often I'll implement an `IDisposable` interface to my classes, then dispose as:

```
// remove children
while (numChildren > 0)
{
    var displayObject:DisplayObject = removeChildAt(0);

    if (displayObject is IDisposable)
        IDisposable(displayObject).dispose();
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why use garbage collection if you have to define a destructor anyways ?

Comment: Garbage collection removes memory allocation; however, without class destructors there's no execution of implementation specific to your instance that may be needed.  Garbage collection is a generic solution; however, implementing an optional dispose method can optimize performance as a best practice.